# my jsp, servlet code to restore image from DB not work correctly

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'am using these JSP,Servlet codes to retrieve images from MySql DB but dose not work. please help.

DB:
    id int;
    icon blob;

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="position:absolute;width:201px; left:1138px ;top:425px ; border-top: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
```

background-color: #fff;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">

```
<% while (rs2.next()) { %>
<TR style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:13px;">

    <TD>
        <img src="photoServlet?id=<%=rs2.getString(1)%>" />
    </TD>
</TR>
<% } %>
```

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    final String User = "root";
    final String Password = "root";
    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, User,        Password);
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select icon from tag where id=?");
        stmt.setLong(1, Long.valueOf(request.getParameter("id")));
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            response.getOutputStream().write(rs.getBytes("icon"));
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PhotoServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>PhotoServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PhotoServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/photoServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: So what is the ErrorMessage? What do you get in `ResultSet rs`?

Comment: Could be (partly) the jpeg. I would save it into the filesystem and compare it to the one residing in your DB (that you also have to write to the filesystem). Saving it should also enable you to examine the "unclear" characters with other tools.

Comment: sorry @dr0i ; This problem occurs because a  had given false guide.         <img src="photoServlet?id=<%=rs2.getString("icon")%>" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying some solutions for this problem i used a jsp that contain srvlet codes and now the images showing correctly. tanx